# jQuery preventing nextAll() to reverse order of menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When menuitem gets clicked its siblings float to the right.

I use jQuery's nextAll() for this.

My problem is, that the order of the floated siblings is reversed and i want them to stay in their initial order.

My question is: 
Is there a jQuery method capable of doing this? 
Otherwise, how could i create my intended behaviour of the menu-items floating right in the correct ordering?

I tried using:

- '.backAll()',
- 'Array.prototype.reverse',
- '$('.menu').nextAll().toArray();' and calling .reverse() on that.

I do understand, that the float does exactly what it should, but i can't grasp when and how i should reorder my menu-items to place them "correctly" (how i want them to).

Do i need to create an array through which i iterate to reoder those menu-items grabbed with .nextAll() or do i have to call the float:right at another time?

Please also see this **[JSfiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/b4wywp30/)** for an example. Clicking a div floats its siblings to the right and reverses the order, which i don't want to happen.

If you could include a small explanation of what behaviour i'm obviously missing / not understanding and pointing me towards it, i would really appreciate that too.

Thank you.

```js
$('.menu').on('click', function() {
  $(this).nextAll().css('float', 'right');
});
```

```css
.menu {
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='menu'>A
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>B
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>C
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>D
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit for the accepted answer:** 
I added the correct answer by @UncaughtTypeError and modified the fiddle, which helped me understand better what happened and removed the else-fork, which was unneeded for showcasing the desired behaviour.
[JSfiddle by @UncaughtTypeError](https://jsfiddle.net/b4wywp30/7/)

**Edit 2:**
@UncaughtTypeError reworked his example from his comment and added it as an separate answer. Please see below for the more indepth explanation.

Comment: look into using css flexbox instead of float

Comment: Something like this? --> https://jsfiddle.net/b4wywp30/4/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thank you for your example. I had to think about the prependTo()-method, how it works and if i could implement it in my reallife code, but it seems to be working fine. Thank you very much for your suggestion and the jsfiddle example.

Comment: When you `float: right`, you are basically reversing the left-right order and positioning the elements flushed to the rightmost edge. If you want to reserve order, use CSS flexbox or grid layout.

Comment: can someone explain to me how i could upvote the correct answer, if it's a comment? going by the FAQ i should just mouseover a comment to see the arrows for upvoting, but nothing. Do i also have to have a certain amount of reputation for upvoting comments on my own questions?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Please provide a separate answer with you suggestion, so i can upvote you and mark your answer as the correct one. Thank you.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Your example breaks when I click on A, and then click on other items that are moved to the right (e.g. "B").

Comment: @Terry Yes, the else-fork needs to be empty, otherwise you can click and reorder the items again.

Comment: Adjusted --> https://jsfiddle.net/b4wywp30/8/ (if this meets the requirements, let me know and I'll add it as an answer officially)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thank you for your reworked example. Yes, please add this as your separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Key Functions Applied:**

1. **.prependTo():** https://api.jquery.com/prependto/
2. **.nextAll():** https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/
3. **.appendTo():** https://api.jquery.com/appendto/
4. **.prevAll():** https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/

The Code Snippet embedded below demonstrates the above functions applied to shift elements right, and then restore them to initial states when clicked on again.

```js
$('.menu').on('click', function() {
  if (!jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('align-right')) {
    if ($('.align-right').length == 0) {
      $('<div class="align-right"></div>').prependTo('.container');
      $(this).nextAll().prependTo('.align-right');
    } else {
      $(this).nextAll().prependTo('.align-right');
    }
  } else if (jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('align-right')) {
    jQuery(this).prevAll().appendTo('.container');
    if (jQuery(this).prevAll().length == 0) {
      jQuery(this).appendTo('.container');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.menu {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.align-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='menu'>A
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>B
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>C
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>D
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
    <div class='submenu'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/b4wywp30/8/

Answer (score 1):

I updated your jQuery to wrap the siblings with an span with a class of right.
Then floated that container right - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Miraidev/a8ov4hs8/)

jQuery

```
$('.menu').on('click', function(){
    $('.menu').unwrap();
    $(this).nextAll().wrapAll('<span class="right">');
 });
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
span.right {
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: Do i understand correctly, that the unwrap() method removes the targeted element, in this case the '.menu' and i need to add it back later, if it's needed again? My problem is, that the .menu-element is needed for further actions in my code and i can't just go and remove it.

Comment: if you look at the fiddle above and use the browser inspect tools you can see that the unwrap() unwraps all of the <span class="right"> tag from all of the .menu items but doesn't remove the .menu item itself when  one is clicked. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Hello You Can try this

```
$('.menu').on('click', function(){
   $(this).nextAll().css('position', 'absolute');
   $(this).next().css('right','129px').next().css('right','67px').next().css('right','5px');
});
```

For working demo you can see [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/dhaval_123/b4wywp30/5/)

Comment: Thank you for your example. I'm curious, did you hardcode the available width of the jsfiddle window into it? How did you get the needed amount for each? I can see, that i should have included in my question, that this example is just an oversimplified showcase for the sake of focusing on the problem of the reordering. This solution would be not feasible, as it is not an flexible application outside of the jsfiddle, but does provide an answer in the scope of my question.